# The URL to Web Worker script is not found with Angular 7+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, web-worker

I´m testing Web Workers and combining them with Angular 7+

This is my app.component.html

```
<div>
  <input type="text" name="lat" placeholder="Latitude" #lat (input)="updateMap( lat )">
  <input type="text" name="lng" placeholder="Longitude" #lng (input)="updateMap( lng )">
</div>
```

This is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'mapa';
  coords: any = {lat: 0, lng: 0};
  worker: Worker;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.worker = new Worker( './app.component.worker.js' );
  }

  updateMap( selector: any ) {
    const key   = selector.getAttribute('name');
    const value = Number(selector.value);
    this.coords[ key ] = value;

    this.worker.postMessage( this.coords );
  }
}
```

This is my Webworker definition app.component.worker.js

```
onmessage = ( e ) => {
    console.log( e );
};
```

All the files are at the same level.

```
project
 -e2e
 -node_modules
 -src
   -app
     -app-routing.module.ts
     -app.component.css
     -app.component.html
     -app.component.ts
     -app.component.worker.js
   -lot of files
 -lot of files
```

When the local server runs, appears this message

> GET http://localhost:4200/app.component.worker.js 404 (Not Found)

I tried to set as relative path

```
'./src/app/app.component.worker.js'
```

But stills not working

What is wrong with my code?
Does exists a best way to do all with Typescript?

Comment: Exactly the same problem, I even include the script path in angular.json script but still do not work.. Have you got any updates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was also facing same issue with this code

```
const worker = new Worker('./web-worker/messenger.worker');
```

Change to

```
const worker = new Worker('./web-worker/messenger.worker', { type: `module` });
```

After this I am not getting this issue with web worker.

> I am using this code on Angular 8.

Comment: If this answer helpfull Please rate up. Thank you

Comment: For me this introduced all sorts of type conflicts. One way I've gotten a worker running under Angular quickly is serving the worker as a .js file from the assets folder.

Answer (score 7):

Do not forget to run: `ng generate web-worker` 
And then restart the angular serve , if not ,it will not compile your worker file into webpack.

Comment: This did it for me. Followed the Angular docs instructions, but did not think to restart `ng serve` to fix the errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For me it just worked by putting the path `src/app/web-worker/messenger.worker`.

Then try the following:

```js
const worker = new Worker('src/app/web-worker/messenger.worker', { type: `module` });
```

Comment: +1 but why have you mentioned like { type: `module` } you can simply write { type: 'module' }. Tilde isnt required